# How do I set a default value for flag in argparse if the flag is given alone

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c',
                    '--cookies',
                    nargs='?',
                    default=5,
                    type=int,
)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.cookies:
    print('cookies flag is set: ' + args.cookies)
else:
    print('cookies flag not set: ' + str(args.cookies))
```

I want it to work so that if the user gives `-c` then we know they want cookies, but we don't know how many cookies they want so we give them 5 by default (`-c == 5` :).

If the user types `-c 25` then we know they want 25 cookies.

If the user does not give a `-c` flag then we know they do not want cookies and cookies flag should not be set.

The way it works as above is that `-c == 5` only when `-c` is not set by the user. But we do not want to give them cookies if they do not ask for it!

If they ask for a specific amount of cookies (ex: `-c 10`), then the code above works fine.

---

I fixed this problem by using a short custom action that checks if the flag is set and if no value is passed in I give it the default value.

This seems a bit convoluted and there must be an easier way. I've searched the argparse docs ([looked at nargs, default, and const](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method)) but couldn't figure out a solution.

Any ideas? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Give a `const` parameter

Comment: Look for `nargs='?'` in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [const](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#const) parameter, which the docs don't do a very good job of explaining.

`default` always sets the value, even if the flag is not provided, unless it is overridden by a user input.

`const` only sets the value if the flag is provided and no overriding value is provided.

The [nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) section has an example of how to use the `const` parameter:

> ```py
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> >>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', const='c', default='d')
> >>> parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='?', default='d')
> >>> parser.parse_args(['XX', '--foo', 'YY'])
> Namespace(bar='XX', foo='YY')
> >>> parser.parse_args(['XX', '--foo'])
> Namespace(bar='XX', foo='c')
> ```

Although the `default` keyword isn't necessary in your case, since you want the value to be `None` if the user does not provide the flag.